# Removing H1 tags in logo on homepage

Tags: magento-2.1

I checked my site and I have three H1 tags on my homepage.

Two are from my logo (Desktop and Mobile version) and the last one is the page title (the one I want to keep)

Which files do I have to modify to only have one H1 tag ?

I'm using Magento 2.1.1 and the Ultimo theme from Infortis.

Thank you and sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: Its a theme thing. Ask ultimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default magento 2  default theme have logo, coming from magento theme vendor.

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header/logo.phtml
```

So you have to check inside Ultimo theme `Magento_Theme/html/header/logo.phtml` file.

Comment: It worked great, thank you !

I just want to add, for anyone having the same issue, that you need to refresh static pages and to flush all caches to see the changes (as always with Magento).

Comment: But what needs to be done in logo.phtml. Can you please explain?